# remove Default Header:"CakePHP: the rapid..." from my "index.ctp"

Tags: php, cakephp

Following header is added to my index.ctp in CAKEPHP 2.XXX ....
How can I remove it ?

here you go:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1><a href="http://cakephp.org">CakePHP: the rapid development php framework</a></h1>
</div>
```

here is my index.ctp file

```
<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<p><?php echo $this->Html->link("Add Post", array('action' => 'add')); ?></p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Created</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- Here's where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php
                echo $this->Html->link(
                        $post['Post']['title'], array('action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])
                );
                ?>
            </td>

            <td>
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->postLink(
                        'Delete', array('action' => 'delete', $post['Post']['id']), array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?')
                );
                ?>
                <?php
                echo $this->Html->link(
                        'Edit', array('action' => 'edit', $post['Post']['id']), array('confirm' => 'EDIT ?')
                );
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

help me plz....

I tried to add default.ctp in "app/layouts" but my application does not work... it shows only default.ctp but not my index.ctp

following is my Controller file....

```
<?php

    class PostsController extends AppController {
        public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

        public function index() {
            $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
        }
        public function view($id = null) {
            if (!$id) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
            }

            $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
            if (!$post) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
            }
            $this->set('post', $post);
        }
         public function add() {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->Post->create();
                if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                   // $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
            }
        }
        public function edit($id = null) {
            if (!$id) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
            }

            $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
            if (!$post) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
            }

            if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
                $this->Post->id = $id;
                if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                //  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been updated.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your post.'));
            }

            if (!$this->request->data) {
                $this->request->data = $post;
            }
        }
        public function delete($id) {
            if ($this->request->is('get')) {
                throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
            }

            if ($this->Post->delete($id)) {
                //$this->Session->setFlash(__('The post with id: %s has been deleted.', h($id))         );
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Add your controller. it seems like you are using default layout. you need to create new layout for header

Comment: @MoyedAnsari...Thiss is my controller file..... so what should be the possible resons....

Comment: do you have layout other than default ?

Comment: see Abishek answer, it is what you are looking for

Comment: thnksssss done.... i have deleted the default.ctp...that was generating default header /footer... i have placed default.ctp and removed two lines generating that header and footer... thnksss

Comment: -1 the standard CakePHP home page contains the following text: [To change its layout, edit: APP/View/Layouts/default.ctp](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/View/Pages/home.ctp#L156), it's only necessary to modify the layout file to ... modify the layout.

Comment: @AD7six... already solved.. thanks for the reply....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below lines to change your default layouts --

```
public function index() {
            $this->layout= 'home'; // new name of layout that you are going  to assign
            $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
        }
```

and put other file name home.ctp in APP/VIEW/layout/

by copying the original default layout default.php inside yours cake/lib/view/ layout directory and remove the footer content as per your need .

your home.ctp should be like as  --

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title><?php echo $title_for_layout?></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!-- Include external files and scripts here (See HTML helper for more info.) -->
<?php
echo $this->fetch('meta');
echo $this->fetch('css');
echo $this->fetch('script');
?>
</head>
<body>

<!-- If you'd like some sort of menu to
show up on all of your views, include it here -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">...</div>
</div>

<!-- Here's where I want my views to be displayed -->
<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

<!-- Add a footer to each displayed page -->
<div id="footer">...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thnks....nice description,,,, i was stuck since last day....finally solved.... thnksssss

Answer (score 2):

Inside your action make layout equals to false

```
$this->layout= '';
```

This will force cakephp not to include any layout for your application.

Incase you want to use your custom layout please follow the steps given in the below links

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html